# How to pass request PostBody parameter with request url? - with HttpClient in Java

Tags: java, automated-tests, java-http-client

With the use of `HttpClient`, I'm trying API Automation. When I'm making GET calls it's fine. But when I'm making POST calls - Getting code: 404 as Http Response.

Example:

```
Request URL : Base_url + service_url + params
Post body : {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}
```

With REST client - I'm getting proper response.
With Java Code - I'm getting 404 error code.

How to make post calls with `HttpClient`?

Comment: You should post your code there, so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

`404` is "FileNotFound" - you should show Exception...

As asked - here's short example with HttpClient:

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build(); 

try {
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://base-url/service-url?params");
    StringEntity body=new StringEntity("{\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}");        
    request.setEntity(body);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

    // Do something with response
}catch (Exception ex) {
    //Something bad happended - deal with it.
    ex.printStackTrace()
}
```